# How to read a chain of Scala function parameters

Tags: scala

I am trying to read the parameter-list of the following 2 functions:

```
1. def foo(action: => String => String) = "bar"
2. def foo(action: => () => String => String) = "bar"
```

1. A function named "foo" which receives a function named "action" which receives/returns ???
2. A function named "foo" which receives a function named "action" which returns a function which returns ???

Comment: My problem in understanding is that I do not know how to decide if one is dealing with functions or simple values as parameters here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. `action` is a passed-by-name function that takes a `String` and returns a `String`.
2. `action` is a passed-by-name function that takes nothing to return a function that takes a `String` and returns a `String`

Now you might ask, "Well, what does it mean for a parameter to be passed-by-name?"  Alright... that's a whole different can of worms.  Basically, a passed by name parameter is only evaluated when it's *used* in the function, and *every* time that it's used in the function.  What this allows for is something like short-circuiting, as follows

```
def orOperator(left: Boolean, right: => Boolean) : Boolean = if (left) true else right
```

In this case, the operator will short-circuit (and terminate without computing/evaluating `right`) if it finds `left` to be true.

So... what you have with these parameters is something similar.  They are functions that do not evaluate—for some reason—unless/until they are named in the function body.  I don't understand the motivation for that, but... that's how it is.  I hope that helps.