# Trying to understand the function signature for Scala parsers e.g. def rep[T](p: => Parser[T]): Parser[List[T]]

Tags: parsing, function, scala, arguments

In the following Parser definition

```
def  rep[T](p: => Parser[T]): Parser[List[T]]
```

I see the argument is a function. There is no type after `p:`, so what is it's type?

Thanks

Basu

Comment: see [this](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/control-abstraction.html#9.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` is actually *not* a function.  An unpreceded `=>` in the type description means that the argument is passed by name.  Basically, it is not evaluated until it is used in the method, and it is evaluated *every time* that it is used in the method.  Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662526/how-to-read-a-chain-of-scala-function-parameters/8662729#8662729) for a bit more info.

Comment: Thanks - both answers were very helpful, and the link too. It's not exactly same question, but definitely enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong here, but I believe with by-name parameters the type is the return type, in this case, Parser[T]

Basically what you see (return type) is what you pass into it

Comment: Well... I think that "return value" is maybe a poor term for that, but, yes, the type that comes after the `=>` is the essentially what you'll pass in.  It can either be something that is already of that type (`val parser = new Parser[Int](); rep(parser)`) or something that _evaluates to_ that type (`rep({val parser = new Parser[Int](); parser.makeAwesome(); parser})`).

Comment: Thanks - both answers were very helpful.

Comment: @destin, yes, should have said, return type (not value), corrected